# Warning thrown by using multiple Iterables on Cactoos Joined class

Tags: java, oop, refactoring, cactoos

While refactoring [Rultor](https://github.com/yegor256/rultor) to use [Cactoos](https://github.com/yegor256/cactoos) instead of Guava, I’m having an issue with [`DockerRun`](https://github.com/yegor256/rultor/blob/5f2e7fa8f6fee577719239933068fb048a175fc9/src/main/java/com/rultor/agents/req/DockerRun.java#L118) class, in the `envs` method.

The current refactored result is:

```
final List<String> entries = new LinkedList<>();
for (final Entry<String, String> ent : extra.entrySet()) {
    entries.add(
        String.format(
          "%s=%s", ent.getKey(), ent.getValue()
        )
    );
}
return new Joined<>(
    DockerRun.envs(this.profile.read(), "/p/entry[@key='env']"),
    DockerRun.envs(this.node(), "entry[@key='env']"),
    new ListOf<>(entries)
);
```

When I build the project, the following warning message is thrown:

```
[WARNING] (...)rultor/src/main/java/com/rultor/agents/req/DockerRun.java:
[132,16] unchecked generic array creation for varargs 
parameter of type java.lang.Iterable<java.lang.String>[]
```

Note that line 132 in my case is the line of `new Joined<>(`

After searching SO I found similar issues, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132692), but no hints on how I can fix the warning message in my case.

So my question is, how can I still concatenate the iterables without getting the warning message, but still use Cactoos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to write it this way:

```
new Joined<String>(
```

Comment: I still get the same warning.