# Javafx: FXCollections.concat() warnings

Tags: arrays, javafx, warnings

I have this code

```
...
ObservableList<Media> audio = controller.getAudioTabPageController().getMediasListView();
ObservableList<Media> image = controller.getImageTabPageController().getMediasListView();
ObservableList<Media> video = controller.getVideoTabPageController().getMediasListView();

ObservableList<Media> medias = FXCollections.concat(audio, image, video);
...
```

but i got this in `FXCollections.concat()`

```
unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter
```

What is exactly going wrong and how would I fix it, as I suppose leaving unchecked warnings in the code is not a good idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java unchecked: unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132692/java-unchecked-unchecked-generic-array-creation-for-varargs-parameter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java unchecked: unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132692/java-unchecked-unchecked-generic-array-creation-for-varargs-parameter)