# Null varargs causes warning: "Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter”

Tags: java, android, shared-element-transition

I have this line of code:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this);
//ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, null); // tried this as well
```

which causes the mentioned warning. The method [signature](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat#makescenetransitionanimation) is

```
ActivityOptionsCompat makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity activity, Pair...<View, String> sharedElements)
```

I wish to send a null `sharedElements` but my code gets a warning.

Comment: Did you mean `Pair<View, String>...`?

Comment: Yes. Just copied it here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat#makescenetransitionanimation

Comment: Always keep in mind a Warning is just a warning. Have a second look and if you are convinced all is OK move on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java unchecked: unchecked generic array creation for varargs parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132692/java-unchecked-unchecked-generic-array-creation-for-varargs-parameter)

Comment: Why do you want to pass a null array anyway?

Comment: I believe the linked duplicate question does not answer the question. I am referring to a method that I do not have control over with.

Comment: @AndyTurner. I don't know what it means if I pass a null sharedElements. I am just curious about null varargs with generics.

Comment: @user1506104 ok - I suppose in that case suppressing the warning is the best you can do (supposing that the method even works as you expect if you don't pass any `sharedElements`, which I'm not sure about, as the docs specifically mention special treatment of the first `sharedElement`)

Comment: Note that the warning should be independent of wheter or not the varargs are empty - you get the warning if you use the method with varargs, if you use it with a generic array you created yourself you don't  - but then you need to suppress the warning where you create the array, which doesn't really change anything.